# shell script to check if a process is up

Tags: scripts, process

I want to check if  a proces is up:

```
[nyxqa@qckmaccg102 scripts]$  ps -fu nyxqa
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nyxqa    19620     1  0 08:42 ?        00:00:00 ./ArcaDirect ITD
nyxqa    19628     1  0 08:42 ?        00:00:00 ./ADViewerWebOps
```

I want to see if ArcaDirect ITD process is up using shell

Answer (score 4):

See `man pgrep`. since I don't have `ArcaDirect`, but do have `NetworkManager`

```
(0)$ pgrep NetworkManager
1400
(0)$ pgrep ArcaDirect
(1)$
```

This is what I typed at the terminal

```
(0)$ pgrep NetworkManager
4011
(0)$ pgrep ArcaDirect
(1)$ if  $(pgrep NetworkManager >/dev/null)  ; then
  echo "Running"
  else
  echo "Restart needed"
  fi
Running
(0)$ if  $(pgrep ArcaDirect >/dev/null)  ; then echo "Running"; else echo     "Restart needed"; fi
Restart needed
(0)$
```

Comment: I suggest redirecting output of `pgrep` to `/dev/null` and checking `echo $?`  output . If output is `0` process has pid, hence is up. If output is `1` or larger  - process is down. Otherwise - good answer

Comment: Can you give me the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `up` you meant that if a process is running at the instant of checking.

You can use `ps` (as you have mentioned) or `pgrep`, as you want to use it in a script i would suggest you to use `pgrep` for its simplicity.

For example lets check if `firefox` is running :

```
$ pgrep firefox  ## Firefox is running, Shows the PID of firefox
17032

$ echo "$?"  ## Exit status is 0 (One (or more) matched process(es) found)
0


$ pgrep firefox  ## Firefox is Not running, Shows nothing

$ echo "$?"  ## Exit code in this case is 1
1
```

There is a very important catch though, in its default form `pgrep` matches the given name as regular expression pattern against process names. So if a process has a name like `firefox_foobar` and you try to check if `firefox` is running by `pgrep firefox`, it will show the PID of the process `firefox_foobar`. Hence you would get the idea that `firefox` is running but actually its not.

Here is an example :

```
$ pgrep firefox_foobar
19002

$ pgrep firefox
19002
```

To get over this issue you should match the exact process name using the `-x` option of `pgrep` :

```
$ pgrep -x firefox_foobar  ## Shows the PID of firefox_foobar
19002

$ pgrep -x firefox  ##Shows nothing as firefox is not running
```

So in a nutshell your script could take the form :

```bsh
if pgrep -x 'ArcaDirect ITD' &>/dev/null; then echo "Running"; else echo "Not running"; fi
```